# Where can I find a PHP function and syntax cheat sheet?

Tags: php

Where can I find a one-page (any size) cheat sheet of PHP functions, syntax, and block constructs?

Comment: Google for PHP syntax cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PCRE, Smarty, PHP](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/100/php-cheat-sheets/)

[WordPress, MySQL, Smarty...](http://techcheatsheets.com/tag/php/)

[PHP ( date formatting, regex...)](http://www.fer.hr/_download/repository/php-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like a [Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/)?

There's also a great page for the results of [variable tests](http://www.deformedweb.co.uk/php_variable_tests.php) that I find very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a lot of PHP cheat sheets on [TechPosters](http://techposters.net/blog/php/) website.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/
is more complete, but I think
http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet-version-1/
spaces it out more

Answer (score 0):

These reference charts are usually referred to as cheatsheets.

Here are a few links, but Google will turn up many others:

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/
http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet-version-1/